# a field that can be null until it receive something in it?

Tags: sql-server-2005

If you have a field(foreign key) in a table that can accept null until there is something in it, so after that the field would refuse null value.

how would you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx), triggers are useful for *"Extending referential integrity between tables."*, which is exactly what you are trying to do. So just use a `FOR UPDATE` trigger and raise an error if the old value was not null but the new value is.

Assuming that you have a nullable column of type int called `SomeId` and your table is called `SomeTable` the following trigger would do the job:

```
CREATE TRIGGER CheckTrigger ON SomeTable
FOR UPDATE
AS
DECLARE @OldId int, 
        @NewId int
BEGIN
    SELECT @OldId = SomeId FROM deleted
    SELECT @NewId = SomeId FROM inserted

    IF NOT @OldId IS NULL AND @NewId IS NULL
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('No!!!!', 10,1) WITH NOWAIT
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

A trigger would be your best bet in that case

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first thing that comes to my mind is creating a trigger that only updates the column if it is null and the new value isn't.